# Laravel application change session path dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The laravel application url will be something like `app.laravel.com\{clientName}`. All the routes will be following the `client_name`, for example `app.laravel.com\{clientName}\home`, `app.laravel.com\{clientName}\profile`. Will load/ render the application depends on the `clientName`.

**`routes/web.php`**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{clientName}', 'middleware' => 'appclient'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

In the **`appclient`** middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $clientName = explode('/', $request->path())[0];
    $client = Client::where('clientName', $clientName)->first();

    if(!isset($client->id)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    Config::set('session.path', "/$clientName");

    return $next($request);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is set the session based on the `clientName` directory. When I login I'm getting TokenMismatchException.

**First question**

Can I store the session based on url with directory like `app.laravel.com\{clientName}` ?

**Second Question**

I saw there is a setting `session.path`, what above I tried is to use that approach. If that is possible, how can I fixed this issue? Is it a good idea to updating the session path in the middleware?

Appreciate any feed back or other approaches

**UPDATE**

- Using `Redis` as session driver
- **In my further investigation the request session token every time generates new one**

Answer (score 3):

What I did is updated the `session.path` & `session.cookie` dynamically.

```
Config::set('session.path', "$clientName");
Config::set('session.cookie', $clientName.'_laravel_session');
```

This is currently working for me.